# iCloud makes it possible for users to "steal" In-App Consumables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, icloud

In my app, users purchase consumables, let's say suitcases, that are stored in Core Data. When the user first installs the app, I give them a freebie to get started. The app can't function without at least one suitcase set up.

But if the user installs the app on their iPhone and then their iPad and syncs the two, they now have 2 suitcases. And if they uninstall the app on either device, then reinstall and sync it, they've just gained an extra one and they can do that indefinitely.

I can see two solutions, but none of them seem right:

1. Add a value to NSUbiquityKeyValueStore when the user first syncs with iCloud. Check this value on first launch. If it's nil, create the freebie, if it's not, sync data. But this creates a problem. What if the user disables iCloud or has no internet connection on first launch. The app would create the freebie, then when iCloud is available, sync the duplicate, and they could do this as many times as they like.
2. Somehow match the default items on each app. I had the idea of matching objectIDs or timestamps, but these would vary and I'm not sure how to handle it.

Does anyone know anything I could do about this?

EDIT:

Using a prepackaged database plus migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error: seems to be the way to go. Will post an answer with code if it works for me.

Comment: Maybe your example is just confusing, but why not just never give them a free suitcase if they already have one? You say the app won't function without a suitcase. Do you mean it will function if they had a suitcase previously and consumed it?

Comment: @chrispix Sorry to make the example so abstract. Basically, you don't "consume" the suitcase, you buy as many as you want and you accumulate them. It's a "consumable" model because it's unlimited, but the item isn't really "consumed" on purchase, which I guess is the key difference.

Comment: I think I see. So the user re-installs, has no suitcases, you give them one. Then they enter some credentials which allow them to pull down their previous suitcases from your server?

Comment: @chrispix In applicationDidFinishLaunching I check NSUserDefaults for the "firstLaunch" key. If it's nil, I insert an object of my Suitcase class (NSManagedObject subclass) and set "firstLaunch". The user installs the app on their iPhone and iPad, "firstLaunch" is nil for both and they get a suitcase on each device. They sync with iCloud and now have 2 suitcases. That's fine, but in the rare case a user clues in on it, they can do this as many times as they like. I think I'll just store and check the device's UDID in iCloud's KVStore. This is all very hacky, but I can patch it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to this, in my opinion, is to store UDIDs in an array in iCloud UbiquitousKeyValueStore.

```
//Store UDID in iCloud
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 5.0) {
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]) {
        NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *store = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];

        //Get array
        NSMutableArray *devices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[store arrayForKey:@"UDID"]];
        [devices addObject:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];

        //Create new array, set to kvstore
        NSArray *newDevices = [NSArray arrayWithArray:devices];
        [store setArray:newDevices forKey:@"UDID"];
        [store synchronize];
    }
}
```

...

```
   //Check if app already installed on device
   NSArray *devices = [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] arrayForKey:@"UDID"];

    for (NSString *UDID in devices) {
        if ([UDID isEqualToString:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]]) {
              //stop the giveaway
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not validating receipts and keeping track of what consumables users own on your own servers you're doing it wrong. You're basically trusting the user to be decent and honest, which is generally always a bad idea.

When you use in-app consumables you should be keeping a log on a sever somewhere of what your users has purchased. That way, every time your app starts up it can verify with the server that the expected number of consumable goods are present.

Comment: Its generally ok to trust your customers. The ones who steal likely would never pay in the first place. Also if you have a nice app they will tell non - technically savvy people to buy it, and then you get more sales. The trick is to make it non - obvious how you would get around buying stuff.

Comment: The problem isn't the in-app purchases because, as you say, you can validate the receipts. The tricky bit is the freebies and how you ensure each user gets the freebie just once.

Answer (score 1):

Use of iCloud implies network connectivity.  As soon as a device connects to the network, you can validate receipts and log consumption of a consumable on your own servers.

Comment: I don't have the skills necessary to set that up, but I believe using iCloud's UbiquitousKeyValueStore should be better than nothing.